# Leveraging powershell to compare two files and email me if a difference has been detected

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to export a list of users who are a member of the administrators group in a text file.  I am then using Compare-Object to look for the differences.  I am looking to automate this process and email me if a difference is found.  I am able to compare the two files and send an email, but I realize I don't know how to add the output of the compare to the email.

Comment: Compare-Object (gc adminreport.txt) (gc adminreport2.txt) | %{if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {send-mailmessage smtpserver mail
.mydomaincom -To administrator@mydomain.com -From user@mydomain.com -Subject 'Admin member changed' }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
$changedEntries = Compare-Object (gc adminreport.txt) (gc adminreport2.txt) | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}  | select -expandproperty inputobject
Write-Host "Changed entries: $changedEntries"
if ($changedEntries) {
    $joinedChangedEntries = 
    send-mailmessage smtpserver mail .mydomaincom -To administrator@mydomain.com -From user@mydomain.com -Subject 'Admin member changed' -Body 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested above code with simple int-arrays.

```
$a = 1..4
$b = 4..8
$changedEntries = Compare-Object $a $b | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}  | select -ExpandProperty inputobject
$joinedEntries = $changedEntries -join ","
if ($changedEntries) { write-host "Found changed entries: $joinedEntries" }
$joinedEntries.GetType()

 IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
 -------- -------- ----                                     --------
 True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

So the code skeleton is the same as posted above.

Comment: I get this error when running the script.  I've tried modifying the mail format.  Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an 
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: the first time i ran it, it just dumped back to a command prompt and no email was sent.  I made changes to the second text file and ran it again.  This time resulting in 
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\script.ps1:4 char:145

Comment: hmm ... thats strange. The intention of this code : `($changedEntries -join ",")` was to convert the `$changedEntries` array into a string ... Can you type `$changedEntries.GetType()`, whats the output?

Comment: @mfarberg, I've updated my answer with the following code: `($changedEntries -join ",")` used at the `-Body`switch. Did you already test it with this change?

Comment: I have tried again, no errors this time, but the body is blank when there are clearly differences in the files.  Just so we stay on the same page, here is what my ps1 file looks like at the moment.        $changedEntries = Compare-Object (gc adminreport.txt) (gc adminreport2.txt) | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}  | select -expandproperty inputobject
Write-Host $changedEntries
if ($changedEntries) {
    send-mailmessage -smtpserver mail.mydomain.com -To administrator@mydomain.com -From user@mydomain.com -Subject 'Admin member changed' -Body ($changedEntries -join ",")
}

Comment: actually I just noticed is does email the "," at the end of the script.  I thought it was dirt on my monitor.

Comment: That would be an indication that `$changedEntries` contains to empty strings.

Comment: I added a prefix to `Write-Host`. Whats the output?

Comment: After I run the script, i then ran echo $changedentries and it returns nothing

Comment: I changed the sideindicator to => and now it I get the differences emailed to me.  Just need to work on the formating.  Thank you